Logic Apps Standard - Servicebus Queue trigger cannot use Content property or Message ID Property
I'm using Logic Apps Standard in Visual Studio Code.
The flow is simple:
Trigger: Servicebus (In App) When messages are available in a queue (peek-lock)
Next Action: HTTP (Call To Beeceptor, to debug messages)
The issue:
When I use the Properties "Content" or "Message ID" in the HTTP Action (to debug the values) I'm getting the following error:

Error:
[2024-04-07T11:11:32.281Z] Executing 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' (Reason='(null)', Id=dd3e3863-a60d-4e5d-a314-e644aef00909)
[2024-04-07T11:11:32.471Z] Executed 'Functions.WorkflowDispatcher' (Failed, Id=dd3e3863-a60d-4e5d-a314-e644aef00909, Duration=187ms)
[2024-04-07T11:11:32.474Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.WorkflowDispatcher. Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Worker.Common: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'HTTP' inputs at line '0' and column '0'. Current flow run operation failed. Exception: '***sanitized***'.
[2024-04-07T11:11:32.678Z] Executed 'Functions.queueconsumer' (Failed, Id=f9912ddf-d1ef-4b5e-8d69-7359444a766c, Duration=6192ms)
[2024-04-07T11:11:32.680Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.queueconsumer. Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Web.Edge: The flow run '08584891185989659111249140401CU00' does not complete successfully. Run status: 'Failed'. Run error: 'An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded.'.

The Same error occurs when using the Message ID property for example.
When I use the Body property, it works and the message I get is:
[{"contentData":"test","userProperties":{"machineName":"xxxxxxxxx","userName":"xxxxx"},"messageId":"439de125-ec06-45c2-9bfa-14a377322cbf","label":"Service Bus Explorer","scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc":"1-1-1970 00:00:00","timeToLive":"14.00:00:00","deliveryCount":1,"enqueuedSequenceNumber":0,"enqueuedTimeUtc":"2024-04-07T11:02:37.774Z","lockedUntilUtc":"2024-04-07T11:03:50.4Z","lockToken":"3bb0c391-d873-4127-9e16-6d43e1aa1168","sequenceNumber":21}]

I tried an expression: json(triggerBody()?['contentData'])
But the same error occurs as when I use Content or Message ID properties.

You are getting an array of messages in your trigger. While @triggerBody()?['contentData'] wouldn't work, @triggerBody()?[0]?['contentData'] would - though it would get the content of the first message only.
You should use the For each action using @triggerBody() as input. This will allow you to process the content of all messages in your array independently: @items('For_each')?['ContentData'].
